# Is socket programming what I need?

Tags: c, sockets

So I'm developing a 2d game using sdl1.2 on linux as a part of a college project and I need the player to be able to submit his score to know his ranking against other players who played the game aswell and I was wondering what am I going to need in order to achieve this with C, is socket programming the answer?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use database (e.g. mysql) to do the job.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.sqlite.org/ It is a light database, easy to use and to integrate in your project.

Comment: You see my main concern is how will the user submit his score online?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if your concern is about the communication, then socket is the only way, of course there are easy to use wrappers around socket, like zeromq etc.
The server would create a server socket and listens on it, and each client will connect to this server and then send the scores and any other data necessary to the server.

For data persistent, you can use embedded database like SQLite or leveldb etc.